# Are React Native Expo Sensors wrong?

Tags: react-native, expo

So as a newbie in React Native, I was going through `Expo Docs` and found the [sensor API](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sensors/) and went to try it out. I copied the code from the Docs and I found a weird behavior of accelerometer, it displayed `z=-1`as my phone was lying on the table. I thought that the accelerometer was supposed to measure the acceleration in a certain direction, but this was measuring the rotation of the phone in 3D space, then I tried the Gyroscope and discovered that it is acting as accelerometer.

#### Are these two swapped, or is this a normal behavior on phones or something else?

[**Acclerometer Expo Docs**](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/accelerometer/)
[**Gyroscope Expo Docs**](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/gyroscope/)

[***Acclerometer Screenshot***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJIuLl.jpg)
[***Gyroscope Screenshot***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIsU7l.jpg)

*Both screenshots were taken on my phone with the same exact position*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are working as expected
The accelerometer works by providing the coordinates of the acceleration vector (gravity vector when device is at rest)
The `z=-1` you got is correct since the accelerometer measurement are relative (might be positive or negative)

[image]

As you can see above the z-axis is pointing towards the front of the device
So while your phone is lying on the table the gravity vector should have coordinates close to (0, 0, -1), and the gyroscope should measure around (0, 0, 0) because the phone is not rotating